# Why are some exceptions not returned?

Tags: nodeos, transactions, error

Sometimes, if an action failed, the details of the exception are returned and sometimes not. However, in the node log, we always can see what happened.

When is the detailed exception returned and when not?

Comment: Do you have an example? Can you post it?